# Converting NSString into asterix(*) format depending on the Length in iOS

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I want to convert the NSString into asterix (*) format depending on the length,So how to do it..

```
if([str1 lenght])
{
    str2 = "*";
}
```

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem to me..."output one * per char in the input".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that you want to create a string containing as many asterisks as the length of the original?

```
NSString *str2 = @"";
str2 = [str2 stringByPaddingToLength:str1.length withString:@"*" startingAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: thanku very much..I got my answer